# Using R to scp files from local to remote

Tags: r, shell, prompt, scp

I am trying to move data files created in R (3.3, Windows 64) to a remote Linux server. Something along the lines of

```
mydata <- data.frame(a = c(1,2), b = c(3,4))
write.csv(mydata, "data.csv")
system("scp data.csv [username@ip.address:~/]")
```

However, this returns

> Warning message: command ... had status 127

which I believe has to do with scp's password prompt. R does not know how to respond to the prompt, so it aborts. I've also tried using `shell()`, but that returns

> 'scp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.```

So I guess my question is: **Is there a way to get R's `system()` function to respond to prompts, or else is there another way to scp from R?**

Additional information:

- The remote IP address changes every day so **I cannot use a passphrase-free SSH key**
- I cannot easily install tools like `expect` or `sshpass` to add to a bash script that would run from R
- There is an `scp` function in the Rcurl package, but it only handles retrieval from remote to local. I'm trying to deposit to remote.

Comment: There's a function for that! See here: [scp](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RCurl/versions/1.95-4.8/topics/scp).

Comment: Alas, that function is for retrieval from remote to local. I'm trying to do the opposite. Thanks, though. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: No it's not: `scp host:/dir/remotefile localfile` and `scp localfile host:/dir/remotefile`. Works both ways.

Comment: What about [cp.remote](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ssh.utils/versions/1.0/topics/cp.remote)?

Comment: I don't think you can do it using `system`, it won't provide a way to input a password. But I don't see why you can't use an SSH key; with options like `-oBatchMode=yes`, `-oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null` and `-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no`  you shouldn't get any prompts for input. It's less secure of course, so use with care.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, I know scp generally can go both ways, but the R function that Lyngbakr is referring to is one-way

Comment: @brm see post. Can't feasibly use with an SSH key since the IP address changes each day. It would sort of defeat the purpose of automating this task, I think

Comment: What does the changing IP address have to do with it? You'd need to adjust your `system` call anyway, right?

Comment: This is just fundamentally silly.  There is a *perfectly well functioning* shell command.  Why not use it?   Despite claims to the contrary, not every command known to man needs to be reimplemented as an R subcommon.

Comment: If it one of the IPs (and hence host id) changes each day, then _maybe scp is not the right tool_.   If you have a hammer ...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel please read the post. I haven't explained the entire pipeline I'm working with for brevity's sake; I assure you if it were as simple as just running scp on the shell I would do that. Vis a vis the IP changing, that is one number that the script can read from an email. i can't automate the daily creation of an SSH key for multiple users.

Comment: @Lyngbakr it appears that only works for Linux; I'm on a windows machine, sadly

Comment: Can you use non-CRAN packages? If so, https://github.com/jeroen/ssh may work.

Comment: @dataprincess I assume this defeats the purpose of the script, but will a solution work where you enter the password manually when prompted or are you looking for a fully automated solution?

Comment: @Lyngbakr if it could be run from R, entering the password wouldn't be the worst thing; but R seems to break down whenever a shell command wants further input.

Comment: @dataprincess I found this elsewhere. Does something like this work? `system("scp data.csv [username@ip.address:~/]", input=readline("Enter your password: "))`

Comment: "I can't automate the daily creation of an SSH key for multiple users." But, you could automate pulling the keys onto the server from a publicly accessible location.